# Changing rm -r autocomplete behaviour for directories with whitespace in their name

Tags: 12.04, rm

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

If I try to auto-complete to delete a directory with spaces in the name, it doesn't work.

Say my directory is called "some spacey directory".  If I type `rm -r some` and hit tab, nothing more autocompletes. So then I type a bit more, say `rm -r some\ s`. Now if I hit tab, it autocompletes but removes the `\` characters giving `rm -r some spacey directory`. This, however, won't delete some spacey directory.  So that's inconvenient.

But when this is a real nightmare:  If you have two directories, say "basic" and "basic with an added feature" and execute `rm -r basic with an added feature` you end up deleting basic.

My question: Is there any reason autocomplete has that behaviour?  Is there anyway I can get rid of it?  This seems like dangerous behaviour in the context of a permanent delete command.

Comment: You don't delete until you press the enter key so I can't see what your issue is.

Comment: Which is fine for the type of person who A) knows enough to know the behaviour of executing that command and B) Never makes mistakes.  I only recently hit the criteria for A) and I don't know many people who meet B).

Comment: I find the behavior odd too when I first hit it, but after realizing what it was about it clicked. I rarely have spaces in directories as that is not a good idea. Even in Windows I avoid the issue. I agree with you that leaving the \ in might be a better aproach, but its something we are all used to now...

Comment: Is there a way to autocomplete directory names with spaces?  And what is the motivation behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Tab completion is working here for directories and files with spaces in their names.

As you can see, Linux does not like spaces in file names. You have to escape them with a \ or use quotes.

```
rm -rf "directory with spaces"
```

`rm` on the command line is harsh and typos can give you problems. I suggest you use the `-i` option for confirmation.

```
rm -i file to remove
```

will give you confirmation, do you want to remove file? and you can abort. I alisis in ~/.bashrc

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

good luck

Comment: `-i` should be default when running recursive commands as root. :)

Comment: By "Tab completion is working here" does that mean you're not getting the behaviour I describe?

Comment: no, if I have a file (or directory) called "file with space", bash tab completes. If I type `rm -i file<tab>` I get `rm -i file\ with\ space`.

Comment: Definitely does not work like that for me.  Though I can do `rm -r "some <tab>` and get `rm -r "some spacey"`

Comment: do you have a custom .bashrc or other config ?

Comment: @Takkat - Well, `-i` should ALWAYS be the default behavior IMO, you can loose a lot in your home directory as well.

Comment: Even when I #comment out any changes I've made in ~/.bashrc and `source ~/.bashrc` I still get the same behaviour.